What to write in build.gradle, settings.gradle and app/build.gradle?
I'm new to this, please help me with basics.
I want to know how gradle works and what a basic code I need in build.gradle, settings.gradle and app/build.gradle. Can you please explain to me? And how to use cmdline-tools in Termux to build apk from project using gradle?
